# What can I change an array of dimension [N] to [None, N]?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to input my data into my model in tensorflow. I have a input vector of size N, but I need to have the shape of the data to be (None, N) in order for tf.matmul(X, weights['h1']) to work.

Let's say I have some two arrays of size N (in my case N = 1000), corresponding to input and output (X, and Y respectively). The input/output data have been already been defined over as x and y respectively. I've posted part of my code below:

```
num_input = 1000
num_output = 1000

#place holders for tensorflow
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_output])

#Define weights/biases
weights = {
  "h1" : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, n_hidden_1])),
  "out" : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, num_output]))
}

biases = {
  "b1" : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
  "out" : tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_output]))
}

#define neural network
def neural_net(x):
  logits_1  = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
  layer_1 = tf.nn.softmax(logits_1) 
  out_logits = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
  out_layer = tf.nn.softmax(out_logits)
  return out_layer
```

When I run my code I get the following error, which I'm sure is due to the mis-match in the dimension of my data, and the placeholders I defined above. Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 69, in <module>
     sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x,Y: y})
   File "/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 887, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
   File "/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1086, in _run
str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
   ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1000,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 1000)'
```

Is there a way to reshape my x and y arrays of shape (N,) to shape (None, N)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `tf.reshape(x, (-1, N))`

Answer (score 0):

If your input data is always going to be of shape `[N]` then I think it makes more sense to define your inputs like that, so:

```
x = tf.placehoder(tf.float32, [N])
y = tf.placehoder(tf.float32, [N])
```

and then when you need to multiply them you can add on an extra dimension:

```
x = tf.expand_dims(x, 0)
y = tf.expand_dims(y, 0)
```

Alternatively you can feed in your data with an extra dimension.

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, 0)
y = np.expand_dims(y, 0)
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x,Y: y})
```